# Is there a Gaussian-like Quadrature for functions with jumps or functions like $\int_a^b\lfloor x \rfloor f(x)dx$?

Tags: integration

How can I numerically find the following kind of integral? :$$\int_a^b\lfloor x \rfloor f(x)dx$$
$\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function and $f(x)$ is a well behaved like a polynomial or an exponential function.

Is there any tool like [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) to solve this problem?

The problem is Google only retrieves advanced applications (like quadrature of high-dimensinal singular integrals...) when I search and I couldn't find any good reference to study.

Thanks in advice for any information or advice here

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest thing to do is to split the integral up over the regions where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is continuous. So in other words, if $a = a_i + a_f$ and $b = b_i + b_f$ where $a_i = \lfloor a \rfloor$, $a_f = \{a\}$ and similarly for $b$, we get something like:

$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^{a_i + 1} a_i f(x) dx + \int_{a_i + 1}^{a_i + 2} (a_i + 1) f(x) dx + \ldots + \int_{b_i}^b b_i f(x) dx$

so each component is just $\int f(x) dx$ over an interval, multiplied by a constant, since $\lfloor x \rfloor$ will be a constant value on any interval between two consecutive integers.